# instaling jdk-7u25-linux-i586.rpm on Centos error

Tags: installation, centos

When i try to install `jdk-7u25-linux-i586.rpm` on my CentOS system it gives me the following error:

```
rpm -ivh --replacepkgs jdk-7u25-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/rt.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/lib/tools.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/lib/tools.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/plugin.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/plugin.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/javaws.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/javaws.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/deploy.pack
Error: unpack could not create JAR file:

        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/deploy.jar

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions
on the download page.
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to resolve this, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks 
Andrew Nel

Comment: Havent u tried installation under root user?

Comment: Have you looked at "the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions on the download page"?

Comment: that installation I posted was when I was logged in as root and I have also tried to install it with sudo to the same effect

Comment: I also have searched for the troubleshooting section but have found nothing specific to this installation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302271/errors-when-installing-jdk-1-7-in-linux may help u

Comment: thanks Vignesh i followed one of the links and found another install which unpacked the rest of the .jar files so this problem has been sorted. appreciate your help guys!